# This is one of the problems with cookie says the book

Tags: html, css

The book says "A user often opens many tabs in the same browser window. If the user browses the same site from multiple tabs, all of the site's cookies are shared by the pages in each tab. this could be problematic in web applications that allow the user to parchase in each tab."

Can somebody explain what the book is trying to say because I don't really understand it.

//tony

Comment: **The book**? What is the book's title?

Comment: “parchase”? Is that a typo, or…?

Comment: This is considered off topic. Also.. the answer to your question is 11.

Comment: @JoshC you got it wrong, it's 42.

Comment: @Vucko that was my next guess.. You should put that as an answer.

Comment: I guess he means `purchase`. Besides of that why would an application allow that, usually you have one cart per user and session. I think `The book` has chosen a bad example here.

Comment: Shopping card management in multiple tabs can get also tricky with serverside state .. the issue there are not limited to cookie-based implementations. I think you might need to try a different book, if what you pasted there was exact citation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the state of the page and the state of the cookies may become inconsistent.

For example, if you put a product in your shopping cart, then open another tab and empty the shopping cart. When you go back to the first tab it looks like you still have that product in your cart, and would be able to change the details for it. If you actually try to change the details, the code needs to be able to handle the sitation where you try to change a product that is no longer in the shopping cart, without crashing horribly.

Comment: You say when you go back to the first tab it looks like you still have that product in your cart but then you say that the code needs to be able to handle the sitation where you try to change a product that is no longer in the shopping cart. What do you mean here ?

Comment: @user2658578: I mean that the first page was rendered with a specific set of cookies, and doesn't automatically change when the cookies change. The code has to handle the sitation when the cookies are changed somewhere else, so that the cookie contents no longer corresponds to the elements that were rendered in the page.